# How do I search dynamically created content?

Tags: search

As you know Wordpress only searches post_content and the_title by default and with a plugin you can get it to search custom meta fields and other things. Thats great and all, but what do you go about content on the page thats not in a meta box or the content field, how do you make that searchable?

Is there a way to insert the dynamic content into post_content so that its searchable?

Is there a better way?

Any suggestions?

Update:

I'm scraping data from a 3rd party website and including it on the page via php in the template. It's on the single post.

Comment: Can you please tell us where these dynamic data come from ?

Comment: What dynamic content are you talking about?

Comment: Custom meta-data can be stored for posts and pages without having a corresponding meta-box in the editor. If the data you are scraping is fairly static, I would recommend simply saving it in the meta-data for the appropriate page or post. The data could then be refreshed via cron. For more temporal applications the transients API may have some use. If the data changes regularly throughout the day or even in real-time, then I feel your best bet would be to save the URL of the page you are scraping in the post/page's metadata, then incorporate a search of all scraped URLs into WordPress's search

Comment: functionality. If you get a hit on any one of those external URLS, the modified WordPress search should return the local WordPress post/page that contains the "hit" URL in it's meta-data rather than a link to the URL itself. Feel me?

Comment: To be clear, I mean that your modified WordPress search should additionally perform searches directly on the live contents of all external URLs that are being ripped, but return your own WordPress posts and pages in place of any "hit" external URLs in the search results. I'll try to elaborate more on all of this in an answer once we shake the hold ;)

Comment: @bosco Currently what I do is kind of like what you described. I save a scrape URL for each post in the meta data (meta: scrapeURL) and then send the scrape URL to the scraper via a var in the scrapers shortcode which is embedded in the template (ie: do_shortcode('[scraper url=$scrapeURL]'). Im trying to feel you on searching the URLs, but I just dont understand how searching the scrape URLs gets the content of the url for the search results, and what it is about the search im modifying?

Comment: Sorry for the obscurity of my comments! Before we head off deciphering them though, let's first establish how frequently the data that's getting scraped changes. The change-rate has performance implications that will need to be taken into consideration when choosing an implementation, particularly in deciding if and how to cache this dynamic data within WordPress. My mention of searching all of the external pages in real-time only makes sense if the external pages change more than many tens of times per day. So does this data change hourly? Daily? Weekly?